# Omission of verbs into state of being

Tags: grammar

If someone asks me, "どこに行くの?", and I have a certain place in mind, but I don't want to say the whole thing, "図書館に行く", can I just say the location instead, omitting the verb?

> 図書館だ would be good enough? Or somehow the に particle must stick in?

Can someone Clarify..?

Comment: you can certainly say 図書館に. but grammatically i think 図書館だ sounds awkward. but i'm not a native speaker so i'll leave this merely as a comment.

Comment: 図書館だ /です are fine.

Comment: 「どこに行くんですか？」「図書館です。」とか「どこ行くの？」「図書館だよ。/ 図書館よ。」とか言いますよね。

Comment: Is Chocolate saying that they're natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

図書館だ isn't natural. You can say 図書館に and 図書館へ but I think just saying 図書館 is more natural.

When someone asks you, "どこに行くんですか？", 図書館です is natural. If you are asked in polite form, you should reply in polite form.

図書館だよ and 図書館よ are also used but 図書館よ would be usually used by females.

Answer (score 0):

Like **A.Ellett** said in the comments, you can just say 図書館 but 図書館に sounds more natural to me. It's like the difference between saying "The library" and "To the library". 図書館だ does sound awkward.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers address the main issue.  But I would like to point out what makes 図書館だ sound unnatural or odd.

The question being asked is どこに行くの, which means "Where are you going?"
To answer 図書館だ would be like responding to that question in English, "It's the library."  Any native speaker of English would understand what you meant, but might possibly think you weren't a native speaker of English.  Likewise in Japanese.